# python:replace characters in file under condition

Tags: python, file-io

I am trying to handle a file `output.dat` by substituting values that exceed `1` with `1`.
E.g if the file contains numbers like:

```
1
2
3
4
```

I want it the output to be:

```
1
1
1
1
```

Comment: *I am trying to handle* ... ???

Comment: @BhargavRao, "handle" here appears to mean "treat" or "use"

Answer (score 1):

If the file is not very large read all the lines filtering any line > 1, then reopen overwriting:

```
with open(infile) as f:
    lines = ["1\n" if int(line) > 1 else line for line in f]
    with open(infile, "w") as out:
        out.writelines(lines)
```

Output:

```
1 
1
1
1
```

This presumes all lines contain only digits as per your example.

Or using `fileinput.input` with `inplace=True`:

```
import  fileinput
for line in fileinput.input(infile,inplace=True):
    if int(line) > 1:
        print("1")
    else:
        print(line.rstrip()) # python3 print(line,end="")
```

To leave the first two lines as is:

```
with open(infile) as f:
    skip = next(f),next(f)
    lines = ("1\n" if int(line) > 1 else line for line in f)
    with open(infile, "w") as out:
        out.writelines(skip)
        out.writelines(lines)
```

Or use enumerate leaving first n lines where index is < 1:

```
with open(infile) as f:
        lines = ("1\n" if int(line) > 1 and ind > 1 else line for ind, line in enumerate(f))
        with open(infile, "w") as out:
            out.writelines(lines)
```

Comment: You can use the [`fileinput`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/fileinput.html) module with [`inplace=True`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/fileinput.html#fileinput.FileInput) to modify the same file in-place.

Comment: @AshwiniChaudhary, yes,  i was going to use it originally but I thought the first way is easier to understand

Comment: Note that you can avoid the `rstrip` call by using `end=''` or a trailing `,` in Python 2.

Comment: @PadraicCunningham,What if i wanted to leave the first two lines intact and process the remaining lines?

Comment: @alex, just call next twice on the file object and write those lines first